# Getting all event of a Bot(user) via Webhook

Tags: slack-api, slack

I have read about the `outbound webhook` and `Event api`. And i am able to install a bot to a team using slack button. `outbound webhook` dosent fit in my scenario i think.

So how can i can get all events(specially whenever this bot receive a msg) using the event api to my webhook.?

Any direction or right way to solve this problem ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outgoing Webhook and Event API are two completely unrelated functions. So you can not get event notifications through an outgoing webhook.

To get event notification your Slack App need to

1. request the correct oath scopes
2. subscribe to the events you want to get in the Slack App config
3. have a script ready to receive the event requests from Slack

Your script will then be called every time the subscribed event occurs.

For all details please have a look at the excellent [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/events-api) about the Event API.

Comment: hi thanks for replying... i already have done all that al...and receiving push on webhook... what i needed to know is,  can i do that programmatically... i mean enabling the event api and setting the webhook url with required event subscription params...?

Comment: no, that is unfortunately not possible. All these settings have to be done manually in the Slack App config page.

Comment: thanks for info.  Also can other user install my bot using ```add to slack``` button... cuz currently i am only able to install it in my own team(using my app)...

Comment: yes, sure. Just point other Slack teams to the URL of your website with the "add to slack button" and they can install it. Btw if you want to interact with the Slack of another team in any way, you want to store the access token that comes out of the Oauth process during installation of the Slack ap.

Comment: So why its not working in my case...any pre-requisite for that.? Screen just got stuck in auth step, keep asking me the team url again n again...in case of my own team url, auth process works smoothly....

Comment: hmm. could have several reasons. pls post you issue as a new question and also add your oauth code fragment.

Comment: No, that's not is. You can install your custom Slack app in other Slack teams without submitting it to the app directory.